# Cloudflareで「ネームサーバーの更新を保留中」がずっと表示される

Tags: dns

バリュードメインからCloudflareへネームサーバーを変えて何日か経ってますが「ネームサーバーの更新を保留中」と表示されます。

何が問題かを教えてください。

[image: ネームサーバー]

[image: ネームサーバーの更新を保留中]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このエラーメッセージは英語だと "Pending Nameserver Update" になるようです。Cloudflare Community に、状況に合わせたトラブルシューティングが 10 種類 (!) 書かれているので、まずはこのトラブルシューティングを全て試されるのが良さそうです。

[Community Tip - Fixing “Pending Nameserver Update”](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-pending-nameserver-update/75415)

Answer (score 0):

設定しなおしたらどう？
それか一旦消してもう一度入れなおせばいいんじゃないかな？

Comment: それでも無理だった